# Device ID from REST API Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

The option --device take a Device ID which is in a hexadecimal format but if I obtain the device ID from REST API it's not in the correct format.

How can I obtain the Device ID in the correct format which i can pass it on command-prompt when I submit my tests ?

Comment: What format are you expecting and what do you actually receive?

Comment: From REST API i obtain the Device ID in the Following format :  sony_xperia_j-4.1.2
as you can see here : https://testcloud.xamarin.com/api_docs/index.html#list-device-configurations-currently-available . But When I submit my tests with command-prompt the --device option take it in the following format : a1a38089. So how can i obtain 2nd format which is correct for command-prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

The cmd line option is "-device**s**" (plural) and that string is generated with Test Cloud based upon the device(s) that you wish to test on.

To create this "list", run through the New Test Wizard and use the ID obtained to then use on your future cmd-line submissions.

> Devices : The devices string generated by Xamarin Test Cloud.
>
> To get this string:
>
> Go to your Xamarin Test Cloud account.
>
> Click New Test Run.
>
> Step through the wizard.
>
> When you reach the final page, copy the ID that >follows the --devices option.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is There a way to generate this Device ID programmatically from code through Xamarin test Cloud REST API ?

Comment: @Marco19 Not that I currently know off, it also seems like the Mobile Center (the new Xamarin Test Cloud) totally broke in this regard as the `--devices` that they present to you when setting up tests is missing...

Comment: @Marco19 you can vote for that feature here: https://testcloud.ideas.aha.io/ideas/XTA-I-135